# Pass PHP variable with button to popup via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I have a table created dynamically with PHP to display requests. In each row of my table there is a button to open a popup. The ID of each request should be transferred to this popup in order to read out all data.

How can I make it so that in a dynamic table (all button names are the same) each button is differentiated, or  recognized which button I pressed? And how can I pass the variable from PHP to the popup via javascript?

I would appreciate any help, I've been trying for days now, but I'm not getting any results.

Here's the table view [image: Table]

Popup window [image: Popup]

```
    <table id="meineTabelle" data-role="table" class="content"
    data-mode="columntoggle" data-column-btn-text="Spalten">
    <thead>
      <div class="tablehead">
        <tr>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority=""></th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority="">1.Projektant</th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority=""></th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority="">2.Projektant</th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority=""></th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority="">3.Projektant</th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority=""></th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority="">4.Projektant</th>
          <th class="thblackborder" data-priority=""></th>
          <tr>
            <th class="">ID</th>
            <th class="">Vorname</th>
            <th class="">Nachname</th>
            <th class="">Vorname</th>
            <th class="">Nachname</th>
            <th class="">Vorname</th>
            <th class="">Nachname</th>
            <th class="">Vorname</th>
            <th class="">Nachname</th>
            <th class="">Titel</th>
            <th class="">Standort</th>
            <th class="">Klasse</th>
            <th class="">Beginn</th>
            <th class="">Abgabe</th>
            <th class="">Beschreibung</th>
            <th class="">Status</th>
            <th class="">Erstellt</th>
          </tr>
        </tr>
      </div>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($Ausgabe as $row) {
    ?>
    <form>
    <tr onclick="dialogOeffnen('loslegen-dialog')">
    <td>
            <?php echo $row["ID"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Vorname"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Nachname"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Vorname2"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Nachname2"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Vorname3"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Nachname3"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Vorname4"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Nachname4"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Titel"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Standort"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Klasse"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Beginn"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Abgabe"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><a href=<?php echo "uploads/" . $FileActualName?>">Link</a></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Genehmigt"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row["Erstellt"] . "<br>"; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="" onclick="">
          </td>
      </tr>
  </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Popup HTML

```
    <div id="body-overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog" id="loslegen-dialog">
      <a href="#" role="button" class="dialog-schließen-button" onclick="dialogSchliessen('loslegen-dialog')">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="textarea">
        <h1><?php echo $row['ID'] ?></h1>
      <textarea placeholder="Platz für Bemerkungen" name="Bemerkungen" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <form classaction="">
      <div class="txt_field">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $fetch_profile['email'];?>" required>
            <span></span>
            <label>E-Mail</label>
         </div>
         <div class="txt_field">
            <input type="text" name="password" required>
            <span></span>
            <label>Passwort</label>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Bestätigen" name="submit">
         <div class="signup_link">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dialoge.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

dialoge.js

```
function dialogOeffnen(dialogId) {
    document.getElementById(dialogId).classList.add("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.add("sichtbar");
}

function dialogSchliessen(dialogId) {
    document.getElementById(dialogId).classList.remove("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.remove("sichtbar");
}
```

If I echo out $row["ID"] for sure it shows me the last ID in my table

Comment: So do you need to get the id with javascript?

Comment: Can you add the popup html here?

Comment: `$Ausgabe` data sample as well?

Comment: Yes, ID with javascript please and the data sample

Comment: Instead of this in the popup, `<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>` , you can get it from the html of the table

Comment: How do I get it from the html?

Comment: Your button has a `value` attribute. You can pass the PHP value in there and read it from JavaScript when you click the button.

Comment: Be sure to check the validity of your HTML. Currently you have `tr` elements that are not in a `<table>` element.

Comment: Something like this `<input type="button" value="<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>" onclick="">` as Emiel mentioned

Comment: @EmielZuurbier so every button got his own ID, thats good. Can you show me how java would read it?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up your HTML a bit. Tables have predetermined structures. That means that a only some elements can be used as a parent or child. For example, you can't nest a `<tr>` inside a another `<tr>`. Learn about [the basics of tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics).

```
<table id="meineTabelle" data-role="table" class="content" data-mode="columntoggle" data-column-btn-text="Spalten">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Vorname</th>
      <th>Nachname</th>
      <th>Vorname</th>
      <th>Nachname</th>
      <th>Vorname</th>
      <th>Nachname</th>
      <th>Vorname</th>
      <th>Nachname</th>
      <th>Titel</th>
      <th>Standort</th>
      <th>Klasse</th>
      <th>Beginn</th>
      <th>Abgabe</th>
      <th>Beschreibung</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Erstellt</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($Ausgabe as $row) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row["ID"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Vorname"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Nachname"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Vorname2"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Nachname2"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Vorname3"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Nachname3"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Vorname4"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Nachname4"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Titel"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Standort"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Klasse"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Beginn"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Abgabe"] ?></td>
        <td><a href=<?php echo "uploads/" . $FileActualName?>">Link</a></td>
        <td><?= $row["Genehmigt"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["Erstellt"] ?></td>
        <td>
          <button class="dialog-open" type="button" value="<?= $row["ID"] ?>">Button</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've changed your button to a `<button>` element because it's a bit more flexible to use. Output the ID of the row in the `value` attribute. Give the button a `class` value to identify it with. We'll need this for JS.

Select the table in JavaScript. Listen for click events that happen within the table. The code below checks if the clicked element (`event.target`) is a button with the class we gave it. If it is, then we'll read the `value` from button and pass it to the open modal function.

```
const table = document.querySelector('#meinTabelle');

table.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.matches('.dialog-open') {
    const dialogId = event.target.value;
    dialogOeffnen(dialogId);
  }
});

function dialogOeffnen(dialogId) {
    document.getElementById(dialogId).classList.add("sichtbar");
    document.getElementById("body-overlay").classList.add("sichtbar");
}
```

Comment: Big Thank you for ur help. I corrected my code and added "onclick="dialogOeffnen('loslegen-dialog')" to my button to open the popup. How do I output the stored variable?

Comment: got an error code "Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost/Datenbank/Test/Anträge_anzeigen.php:104"